# Как межмодульнно работать со структурами и подпрограммами?

Tags: c, функции, структуры, модульность, модули

Как межмодульнно работать со структурами и подпрограммами скажите пожалуйста? В частности у меня проблема это с использованием структур Student и Marks, а так же такой функцией как action, которая производит заданное действие над заданным массивом структур Student'ов (выполняет функцию переданную параметром)

> **main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <rpc.h>

int main() {
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8); //Windows10

    size_t n;

    printf("Введите число студентов: ");
    scanf("%i", &n);

    Student *students = Read_Students(n);

    action(students, n, &Sort);

    for (size_t i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%i %i\n",students[i].marks.History,students[i].marks.Math);

    return 0;
}
```

> **actions.c**

```
#include <rpcndr.h>

void InsertionSort(struct Student *students, int *arr, int n) {
    size_t tmpIntElement, location;
    Student tmpStudElement;

    for (size_t i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        tmpIntElement = arr[i];
        tmpStudElement = students[i];
        location = i - 1;
        while (location >= 0 && arr[location] < tmpIntElement) {
            arr[location + 1] = arr[location];
            students[location + 1] = students[location];

            location = location - 1;
        }
        arr[location + 1] = tmpIntElement;
        students[location + 1] = tmpStudElement;
    }
}

void Sort(Student *students, int n) {
    int *arr = getSredneeArr(students, n);
    if (!equals_el(arr, n)) {
        InsertionSort(students, arr, n);
    }
}

void action(Student *students, int n, void (*f)(Student *,int)) {
    f(students,n);
}
```

> **functions.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dxtmpl.h>

void Read_Student(Student *student) {
    printf("\tИмя студента : ");
    scanf("%s", student->name);
    puts("");

    printf("\tФамилия студента : ");
    scanf("%s", student->surname);
    puts("");

    printf("\tОценка студента по\n");

    printf("\t\tМатематике = ");
    scanf("%i", &student->marks.Math);

    printf("\t\tИстории = ");
    scanf("%i", &student->marks.History);
    puts("");
}

int *getSredneeArr(struct Student *students, int n) {
    int *arr = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        arr[i] = (students[i].marks.Math + students[i].marks.History) / 2;
    return arr;
}

int equals_el(int *arr, int n) {
    size_t i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr[i] == arr[j];
}

Student *Read_Students(int n) {
    Student *students;

    students = (Student *) malloc(sizeof(Student) * n);
    puts("");

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Cтудент %i\n\n", i + 1);
        Read_Student(&students[i]);
    }

    return students;
}
```

> **structs.c**

```
#define MAXBuffer 256

typedef struct Marks {
    int Math;
    int History;
} Marks;

typedef struct Student {
    char name[MAXBuffer];
    char surname[MAXBuffer];
    int srMark;
    Marks marks;
} Student;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Как межмодульнно работать со структурами и подпрограммами скажите,
>   пожалуйста?

Для ваших целей вашу систему файлов нужно чуточку подкорректировать. :)

Я бы на вашем месте оставил после корректировки вот такие файлы :

- studs.h
- studs.c
- main.c

В **studs.h** , по всем правилам, будет храниться то, что у вас в **structs.c** + прототипы функций, которые у вас реализованы в **actions.c** и **functions.c** ( позже объясню, почему я так сделал ).

Не забудьте про [includes guard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810115/c-include-guards) :).

---

В итоге, заголовочный файл может быть таким ( лучше бы вам прочитать комментарии ):

```
#ifndef _STUDS_H_ 
#define _STUDS_H_

#include <stdint.h>

#define MAX_BUFFER 256 /*такие обычно названия для препроцессорных определений */

/* Забыли здесь про платформонезависимость + можете стать жертвой выравнивания.*/
/* Хочется "int" - заменим на "int32_t".*/

typedef struct Marks {
    int32_t Math; 
    int32_t History;
} Marks;

/* Если с "Marks" всё может остаться хорошо (при неизмененности типов) ,*/
/* То со "Student" всё может получиться печально. */
/* Допустим, я , как неопытный, захотел поменять MAX_BUFFER на 271. */
/* Тогда sizeof(Student) мне покажет 556, а по факту размер - 554. */
/* Таким образом, вы выделяете больше памяти, чем нужно. */
/* Предлагаю применить директиву "#pragma", чтобы не было проблем, */
/* возникающих из-за выравнивания */

/* В некоторых случаях эта директива может быть недоступной, 
/* но если есть возможность - почему нет? :) */
#pragma pack ( push, 1 ) 
typedef struct Student {
    char name[MAX_BUFFER];
    char surname[MAX_BUFFER];
    int32_t srMark;
    Marks marks;
} Student;
#pragma pack ( pop )


/* При объявлении прототипов переменные аргументов использовать не обязательно. */
/* Достаточно указать их типы. */

void Read_Student( Student* );
int* getSredneeArr( Student* , int );
int equals_el( int* , int );
Student* Read_Students( int );

void InsertionSort( Student* , int* , int );
void Sort( Student* , int );
void action( Student*, int , void (*) ( Student* , int ) );

/* В прототипах опять проблемы с платформозависимостью, но это вы решайте сами. */
/* Также, в тех аргументах, где говорится о количестве, я бы на вашем месте */
/* вместо "int" писал "size_t" */
/* ( а у вас такие есть, но опять же давайте сами, я вас направил ) */

#endif
```

Файл `studs.c` - это просто совокупность `actions.c` и `functions.c`.
Объединить их в один нужно потому, что каждая функция предназначена именно для работы со студентами (их "чтение" , их "сортировка" и т.д.).

Если бы вы написали ".c" - файл, который бы сортировал любой тип (что вы не сделали, потому что это ,IMO, невозможно), то тогда его бы можно было вынести отдельно, а так - "нетушки" :D

"Копипастить" не буду, потому что и так понятно, что в нём должно находиться (`actions.c` + `functions.c`, как я уже писал).

---

Если в `studs.c` вам нужно что-то "includ"ить (а вам 100 % нужно будет включить там **studs.h** и ,судя по коду, **stdio.h** тоже), то делайте это прямо там, не стесняйтесь :)

(не мог это не написать, потому что некоторые "пугаются" и просто включают, например, *stdio.h* именно в заголовочный файл, где он там НЕ нужен, лишь бы не включать ничего в ".c"-файлы)

Если не знали, то на будущее подмечу, что пользовательский заголовочный файл подключают, используя уже двойные кавычки, а не символы "<" и ">" :

```
#include "studs.h"
```

---

Если у вас *gcc* - компилятор , и ваш заголовочный файл находится в том же месте, что и остальной код, то можете скомпилировать это так:

```
gcc -o main main.c studs.c
```

( Настоятельно рекомендую пользоваться ключами `-pedantic`, `-Wall` и `-Werror`, чтобы ваш код был более чистым и эффективным )

### Некоторые замечания, о которых я не написал вам раньше :

- Если уж вы передаёте "int" в функцию, которая работает с беззнаковой составляющей (количество студентов), то проверяйте хотя бы, чтобы ваш "int" не был меньше нуля (количество студентов не может быть отрицательным по смыслу).
- У вас есть функции, которые работают только в предеах модуля (те,
  которые вы не вызываете нигде, не считая тех функций, которые
  находятся в этом же модуле). Их надо пометить ключевым словом
  "static".
         Для примера: вы используете `Read_Student` внутри `Read_Students`, но нигде больше, поэтому к прототипу функции в
  начало добавьте `static`. Можете ещё [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319361/static-function-in-c)
  заглянуть.
- У вас не бывал "segmentation fault" при работе вашей программы?  У
  меня это случилось почему-то, не раз и в разных местах (причём, это случалось при изначальном
  виде).

Предусмотрите все случаи, и реализуйте ваши функции правильно. Удачи :)

**UPD** : вот ещё для вас [ссылочка](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/167723/what-should-and-what-shouldnt-be-in-a-header-file), чтобы вы посмотрели, чему следует находиться в заголовочном файле.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы все файлы вашей программы знали о том, что такое структуры `Student` и `Marks`, надо переименовать `structs.c` в `structs.h` и включать его во все .c-файлы

```
#include "structs.h"
```

Вас это интересовало?