# как разбить main.c на несколько маленьких файлов

Tags: c, eclipse, компиляция, препроцессор

Начинаю работать в Eclipse и компилирую файл main.c
всё компилируется, всё нормально. Но хочется простого хомячьего комфорта.
И хочется некоторые куски исходного текста держать в отдельных файлах
и чтобы препроцессор (или кто там)
просто сводил все мелкие файлы перед компиляцией 
обратно в большой и громоздкий main.c,
не пытаясь откомпилировать эти файлики по отдельности до объединения всего исходного текста и ругаясь, мол unknown type name 'uint32_t' part101.c

Существует ли нормальная директива типа #just_include_and_shut_up
для препроцессора? Или, может, в Eclipse есть что-нит такое...

Comment: Нет смысла. Лучше разбивать на несколько .c-файлов.

Comment: Есть. Файлы бывают `.h` и `.c`, вот имееноо `.h` - нужны для сборки всего проэкта, а `.с` нужен для "реализации" (например в obj). Но при этом проэкт должен состоять из "модулей", и каждый модуль должен ссылаться на один `.с` файл, а `.h` файл не должен содержать кода (или данных для дата-сегмента) вообще. А вот как правильно настроить eclipse что б он сие понимал - не подскажу.

Comment: Директива для этого, думаю, не нужна. Нужно правильно скомпоновать (сконфигурировать) проэкт. Из директив понадобится только три `#ifndef module1_h` `#define module1_h` `#endif`.

Answer (score 2):

`#include` делает ровно то, что Вам нужно - вставляет содержимое файла. Очень часто (например в бусте) делают куски кода в файлах с расширением imp или inl, куда и вставляют код. А потом их подключают через `#include "func.imp"` и так далее. Зачем нужно такое расширение? потому что некоторые IDE (например, эклипс) пытаются проявить интеллект и компилировать файл, если у него расширение c или cpp.

Такие include можно делать многократно вложенные, главное, не рекурсивные (тогда нужно уже защищать через ifndef-define-endif).

Если эклипс будет дальше бузить - переходите на те редакторы, которыео нормально к подобному относятся, к примеру vim/emacs.

Answer (score 1):

У вас слишком размытый вопрос, но если своими следующими словами я вам как-то помог, то это прекрасно :)

<s>О, философия подъехала</s>

> ...большой и громоздкий `main.c`

Если он , действительно, у вас такой, то это значит, <s>что вы и есть хомяк :D</s> что у вас либо нет функций, либо их мало, либо они есть, но очень плохо реализованы, либо что-то в совокупности.

А решение этой 'громоздкости' только одно : создавать функции, чётко представляя свою предметную область, то есть сначала считать ножки на стульях, а потом количество костей на ногах бабушек-сноубордистов не нужно.

Когда вы решите этот вопрос, и получите **негромоздкий** `main.c`, то вам нужно будет правильно это всё распределить по вашей(-им) директории(-ям). Недавно мы решали подобную проблему, по которой вы можете 'пробежаться' [вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/817300/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8).

По моему личному опыту скажу, что в "Си" лучше соответствовать следующему шаблону : 1 предметная область - 1 файл с `.c`-расширением + 1 с `.h`-расширением. Если вы представляете свою сложную задачу, как несколько маленьких, то вы вполне можете делать несколько *c*-файлов и заголовочных файлов (но не переусердствуйте).

---

И вот только на этом моменте я ,скорее всего, понял вашу проблему.

Допустим, что сама команда для компиляции у вас правильная.

Представим ситуацию, что :

- У вас 1 заголовочный файл `chairs.h`, в котором находятся определения
  структур, прототипов функций и т.д.
- `chairs.c`, в котором находятся сами функции, которые **должны быть связаны**
  с определениями из `chairs.h`.

  А ещё у вас есть `main.c`, в котором вы подключили заголовочный файл `chairs.h`, но всё равно ничего не компилируется,верно?

`chairs.h` нужно подключить в самом `chairs.c`, и тогда проблем с компиляцией у вас не должно возникнуть.

---

Не бойтесь что-то подключать в любой `.c`-файл. Если в двух файлах с реализациями ваших функций (например, те же `main.c` и `chairs.c`) вы подключаете один и тот же заголовочный файл стандартной библиотеки, то препроцессор всё равно не позволит из-за своего include guard работать лишний раз с копиями (почитайте про [include guard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810115/c-include-guards), чтобы у вас при создании заголовочного файла не было проблем) :)

Если у вас всё сделано так же, как я описал выше , и у вас всё равно какие-то проблемы, то это означает, что вы либо сделали что-то не так, как я вас направил, и вам для полного "разжёвывания" нужно просто смотреть примеры, как это делают другие.

Будете искать ответы на такие вопросы, как у вас на данный момент, то  <s>станете хомяком</s> компилятор будет сам вас затыкать, как сейчас, потому что u've done it wron', но он вам помогает :)

P.S:

А `unknown type name 'uint32_t' part101.c` означает, что у вас в файле `part101.c` не узнаётся такой тип, который определён в `<stdint.h>`. Значит, вам нужно подключить туда этот самый заголовочный файл, либо подключить **пользовательский** заголовочный файл, в котором находится `<stdint.h>` (зависит от случая).

Comment: Мне понравился ответ от KoVadim. Но для Вас я хочу уточнить ситуацию. Пишу чтение IR-сенсора через ADC для STM32F103. Утилита STM32CubeMX сгенерила мне main.c и прочие свистелки. Редактирую это в AC6 WorkBench (Eclipse based IDE).
А main.c уже  напичкан вызовами HAL-функций для периферии. Всё такое большое, длинное. Букав много. Пока до main()-мышью догребешь - уже и обед.
Захотелось романтики, чтоб не видеть всех этих физиологических подробностей инициализации периферии - держать мой маленький код в отдельном файле.
Сейчас  (по совету KoVadim) храню свои 50 строк в отдельном *.imp-файле.

Comment: Если вы посчитали тот ответ правильным и следуете его совету ,то ,пожалуйста, отметьте его соответствующим образом. Я отвечал на ваш вопрос в рамках того, что было в нём описано. Про генерацию кода от каких-либо утилит не было упомянуто ни слова. Во всяком случае, был рад помочь, если хоть как-то это сделал :)